# Html list doesn't display the items correctly in sorted order when a new element gets added to the list array in vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, vue.js

> Html list doesn't show elements correctly in descending order after I add a new element to the array but works fine on onMount

I have an array to render as html list in descending order of the values. So I used v-for to do that. 
After rendering the array, I need to add more elements one by one and these elements need to be added in correct order. so I used sort method.

```
<script setup>
  import { computed, onMounted, reactive, ref, watch } from 'vue'
  import { useCarStore } from '@/stores/car'

  const carStore = useCarStore()

  const cars = computed(()=>{
    const cars = carStore.get_cars // pinia (state management)
    cars.sort((a,b)=> b.value - a.value)
    return cars
  })

  const addCar = () => {
    carStore.addCar() // pinia (state management)
  }
</script>

<template>
 <div class="cars">
   <Car
    v-for="(car, i) in cars"
    :key="i"
    :car="car"
    />
 </div>
 <button @click="addCar">add car</button>
</template>
```

pinia code:

```
export const useCoinStore = defineStore('coin', {
  state: () => ({
    cars: []
  }),
  getters: {
    get_cars(state){
      return state.cars
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async addCar(){
      // got a car from an api
      this.cars.push(car)
    }
  }
})
```

**Now the problem is the list doesn't get rendered correctly after I add a new element to the array** although sort method works fine. The correct order gets rendered only when I reload the component/page

Comment: perhaps there's an error in your *code*?

Comment: I found no error. but here you can see I have just added some of the code to get the idea.

Comment: that's a start ... perhaps your pinia code is wrong? without knowing what `carStore` even is, it's hard to say

Comment: my pinia code has no problem. everything works fine. but when a new element gets added only rendering doesn't happen correctly, otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: I guess you *know* it's right, because your site works as expected

Comment: Can you provide the code from pinia?

Comment: Not sur, but your problem is when you added a car the display is not update, but if you inspect your array you see the new car added inside, am i wrong?

Comment: @RaphaelRollet you are absolutely correct. the display doesn't update.

Comment: @GionRubitschung The code is confidential. But I've tried to portray the issue. See I have just added some of the code to give you an idea

Comment: @RaphaelRollet display updates by adding a new list item. but it doesn't change the previous items to be in the sorted order. now you got my point ? sorry for my bad explaining ability in english

Comment: What i understand is: the car is added, but the sort is not trigger. So for me is the binding problem.
Replace the `this.cars.push(car)` by `Vue.set(this.cars, index, car)`.
You have to import Vue inside the pinia store.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is updated when you inspect it, but the display is the old version without the new added item it's because you have a binding issue.

You can solve it with different way the most easier is to use the property `Vue.set()`.

```js
Vue.set(array, index, newItem)
// Inside a vue instance you can do this.$set()
```

The second way, and maybe good for you is to try to save the binding:

```
 const cars = computed(()=>{
    return carStore.get_cars.sort((a,b)=> b.value - a.value)
 })
```